# Migrating huge SVN repo. to Git -- How to rewrite history and still keep in sync?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration, git-svn

### Problem

I have been working with a beastly SVN repository that is 177GB and am trying to migrate it to git.  Clearly there are lots of files that don't need to be in there.

After I am done rewriting all the history (which takes quite a while for each repository), I eventually need to synchronize it back with SVN.  But after the history rewrite, the revisions no longer match what `git svn` expects, so things break.

### Goals

1. Copy all SVN history to git
2. Remove junk from the repositories in git (way easier than doing it in SVN)
3. Freeze the SVN codebase
4. Make SVN read-only
5. Apply any commits since the start of the migration to the git repositories
6. Push the final SVN commits to git
7. Merge repositories, post-migration cleanup, etc...
8. Be happy

### Steps (simplified)

- SVN repository A is migrated to Git at revision X

  ```
  git svn clone <args>
  ```
- Big objects in A are removed from the git history

  ```
  git filter-branch --force --index-filter                       \
          'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch some/fat/badness' \
          --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
  ```
- Push these changes -- with the rewritten history, we are now at revision X - n

  ```
  git push -u origin --all --force
  git push --tags --force
  ```

  *... developers commit stuff to svn; now at revision (X + k)*
- Sync with SVN using **???**

^ What do I do to not break the synchronization in the last step?  `git svn fetch` is of no use as-is as it pulls revisions (1 + (X - n)) to (X + k) and completely breaks everything after I rebase.

Ideally the solution would be scriptable and wouldn't require knowing what revision I was at before I rewrote the history.  (But even then... how do you tell git that revision (X - n) corresponds to SVN revision X?)

### Reference

- [Atlassian's migration guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/migration)
- [GitHub's cleanup guide](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)

Comment: BTW in case anybody is wondering, the reason the history is not being cleaned up post-migration is because BitBucket forces any repository that's over 2GB to be read-only.  And I don't know how I can make these kind of historical changes with the repository as read-only.

Comment: If you destroy history anyway, why you don't want just fetch some "last N" changesets instead of full clone?

Comment: Okay -- how is that done without breaking things?  Keep in mind I am using `git svn`.

Comment: `git svn -s -r SOME_OLDER_COMMIT:HEAD URL/OF/REPO` + `git svn fetch`